# pip check from requirements but not install

Tags: python, pip

It's very annoying waiting 50 packages to be installed from a `requirement.txt` (generated by `pip freeze`from a virtual env), and to find out at 35th that a version of blabla couldn't be found.

Is there any way of massive check of availability of package versions, before asking to install from `requirement.txt`? I didn't find any mention of this on `pip help install`

Comment: try to install each package individually

Comment: that's out of option. There are 50 of them

Comment: Nope, there is no such feature afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new python script in same folder in which `requirement.txt` is there.

```
import pip


def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])


with open('requirement.txt') as requirement_file:
    for row, line in enumerate(requirement_file):
        try:
            install(line)
        except:
            print ('Unable to install {}'.format(line))
```

and run this python script.

Comment: @dengan no problem bro ;)